# Как сделать поиск по бд городов?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть БД всех городов мира, нужно сделать автоподсказку при вводе, проблема в том что в БД более миллиона записей и обычный LIKE заставляет бедную БД задуматься секунд на 10

Comment: Неправильно выбрана технология. Используте что нибудь, что заточено под такие нужды. (sphinx search, solr, elastic search)

Comment: Проиндексируйте поле и используйте LIKE-поиск только по префиксу, а также установите разумное предельное количество возвращаемых результатов (LIMIT).

Comment: LIKE  только по префиксу это LIKE  'текст%' ?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127720/long-query-time-in-php-mysql-select

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй сделать что б начинало искать после введенных 3-ех первыйх букв, тогда и нагрузка будет меньше!
Я использовал https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Даже 5 букв не спасает

Answer (score 2):

Решал подобную задачу. Для начала структурируйте сами данные. Разбейте города по странам и присвойте каждому городу свой приоритет (например, столицы - 1, миллионники - 2, областные центры - 3 и т.д.). Далее запускается поиск по этому приоритету (и выводятся города только той страны, к которой они относятся). В начале подсказки выводятся наиболее значимые объекты (например, всего в подсказке выводится 5 городов). Далее, если не хватает данных для вывода по самому высокому приоритету, выводятся данные по более низкому и т.д. Из плюсов здесь также будет то, что наиболее вероятные города-подсказки (которые и нужны пользователю) будут в верхней части списка.

Что-то мне подсказывает, что у вас не проставлены/неверно проставлены индексы. Миллион городов это относительно небольшая таблица, LIKE должен выполняться за доли секунды.

По хорошему, здесь вообще нужна структурированная геобаза по типу VK (где города упорядочены по отдельным географическим районам), т.к. даже в рамках одного района встречаются населенные пункты с одинаковым названием. Чтобы их не путать нужна подсказка с указанием географического района, к которому относится населенный пункт.